# How to build a function or mixin to check Sass or Sass library version

Tags: css, ruby, sass

I'm building a Sass library and I want to let the user check both the library and Sass versions to see if he can safely output his code.

The library version is defined as a `$variable` on the index `.sass` file, and I wanted to use a function/mixin that could be like `required_versions($library, $sass)`, where both arguments are the minimum required versions to be used on the project.

For Sass version checking, I saw this http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/when-and-how-to-support-multiple-versions-of-sass--cms-20935, but I want something more acurate.

At first I thought I could use [Version](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Version.html#version-instance_method) to get Sass version, and [version_gt](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Util.html#version_gt-instance_method) or [version_geq](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Util.html#version_geq-instance_method) to compare the versions stated in the function/mixin arguments with the Sass' [Version](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Version.html#version-instance_method) `:number` and the library version defined on its index file, but these seem to be Ruby's only methods.

Is there a way to make something like this?

Comment: If you have not looked at Compass, I highly urge you to do so.  Compass extensions allow you to set version dependences.  http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/extensions/

Comment: I don't want to rely on third-party dependencies. Only Sass here.